I have problem rendering custom theme logo



This is my custom theme logo problem in Drupal 11

Welcome to Drupal Answers! Unfortunately, This is my custom theme logo problem in Drupal 11 does not explain what problem you have, what you tried to fix it, and why what you tried did not work for you. Three screenshots do not make a question.

The path is relative to the URL in the browser, not relative to the twig file. So either use a domain absolute path
<img src ="/themes/custom/noble_theme/assets/noble.png">
or prefix with the theme directory variable
<img src ="/{{ directory }}/assets/noble.png">
